# Saving A UIView As A Native Resolution Image

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am able to save the contents of a UIView as an image to the library.

The image i am trying to save is very a good resolution on the app, but saving it to the photo library reduces the resolution significantly. The image i am trying to save, is of the same width as the screen but many times the height of the screen.

The image i save looks like how i want on the UIScrollView in the app but the image it saves has a lower resolution than the actual image. How can i prevent it from doing this?

Thanks in advanced :D

edit: adding the code...

```
- (void) saveImageToLibrary
{
    UIImage* image;// = nil;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scrollview.contentSize);
    {
        CGPoint savedContentOffset = scrollview.contentOffset;
        CGRect savedFrame = scrollview.frame;
        scrollview.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
        scrollview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollview.contentSize.width,  scrollview.contentSize.height);
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollview.contentSize.width,  scrollview.contentSize.height);

        [scrollview.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        scrollview.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
        scrollview.frame = savedFrame;
        self.view.frame = savedFrame;
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil,nil,nil);
}
```

i hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys and goyals... i think i figured out the problem.

the issue is the iPhone simulator. depending on the hardware you are sumulating, image will be optimised for the resolution of the sumilator.

im not entirely conviced by this because i was previously simulating an iPhone 5 (which has retina display), but simulating iphone 6 seems to work fine.

here is a link if you want to follow further details or if you want to add to this thread :D

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032528/uiimage-image-loaded-from-appbundle-is-saved-at-lower-resolution-in-app-direct
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the correct scale when you try to create the image? Could you post the code?

Comment: im not sure what you mean by scale. i thought that it would save the image as per the dimensions of the UIView it is contained inside. i am adding the code to this thread.

Comment: The scale means if the image would get the 2x ou 3x multiplier in its size. You can see in this link (https://coderwall.com/p/jdwyta), if you use 0 as scale, it'll use the right scale automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(scrollView.contentSize, scrollView.opaque, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
```

**EDIT**

You can also try setting the scale to zero:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(scrollView.contentSize, scrollView.opaque, 0.0);
```

Does that help you?

Comment: That didnt do anything. the saved image is still blurry when saving a large image.

Comment: That should theoretically increase the scale because your devices screen has probably a scale of `2.0` or more...